# MySQL - get row if another rows value is set for a group of records

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following MySQL database table which is being populated by a form plugin. I would like to extract the value for the field_name "your-email" for each each group of records (grouped by "submit_time" column value) and if the field_name "checkbox-signup" has a value of "Signup for our email newsletter".

sample data-table (table name = dbplugin_submits):

```
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
    |submit_time|field_name     |value                            |order|
    |---------- |-------------------------------------------------------|
    |1400149594 |checkbox-signup|Signup for our email newsletter  |4    |
    |1400149594 |your-message   |Testing newsletter signup        |3    |
    |1400149594 |your-subject   |Testing newsletter signup        |2    |
    |1400149594 |your-name      |Test User 1                      |0    |
    |1400149594 |your-email     |Test User@company1.co.uk         |1    |
    |1400149627 |your-email     |Test User2@company2.co.uk        |1    |
    |1400149627 |your-name      |Test User 2                      |0    |
    |1400149594 |Submitted From |188.66.94.194                    |10000|
    |1400149594 |Submitted Login|admin                            |9999 |
    |1400149627 |your-subject   |Testing again - please ignore    |2    |
    |1400149627 |your-message   |                                 |3    |
    |1400149627 |checkbox-signup|                                 |4    |
    |1400149627 |Submitted Login|admin                            |9999 |
    |1400149627 |Submitted From |188.66.94.194                    |10000|
    |1400149887 |your-name      |Test User 3                      |0    |
    |1400149887 |your-email     |user.three@company2.co.uk        |1    |
    |1400149887 |your-subject   |TESTING FORM FOR ANALYTICS       |2    |
    |1400149887 |your-message   |PLEASE IGNORE                    |3    |
    |1400149887 |checkbox-signup|                                 |4    |
    |1400149887 |Submitted From |188.66.94.194                    |10000|
    |1400768741 |your-name      |Test User                        |0    |
    |1400768741 |your-email     |testuser@company.co.uk           |1    |
    |1400768741 |your-subject   |Testing                          |2    |
    |1400768741 |your-message   |Please ignore - just testing     |3    |
    |1400768741 |checkbox-signup|Signup for our email newsletter  |4    |
    |1400768741 |Submitted Login|admin                            |9999 |
    |1400768741 |Submitted From |188.66.94.19                     |10000|
     -------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have tried the following but I am not sure if an inner query is the correct approach here:

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    `dbplugin_submits` a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  `submit_time`
            FROM    `dbplugin_submits`
            GROUP BY `submit_time`
        ) b ON a.`submit_time` = b.`submit_time`
          AND a.`field_name` = 'checkbox-signup'
          AND a.`field_value` = 'Sign up for our email newsletters'
          AND b.`field_name` = 'your-email'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not tested but something like this should work:

```
SELECT a.submit_time, b.value FROM dbplugin_submits a 
JOIN dbplugin_submits b ON (a.submit_time = b.submit_time AND b.field_name='your-email')
WHERE  a.field_name = 'checkbox-signup' AND a.value = 'Signup for our email newsletter'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. Self-join is the way to go about this. The query you have framed is almost there. However, you could achieve with a very simplistic self-join query.

This is the way I'd write it for SQL Server **(Tested on SQL Server)**.

```
    SELECT      email.submit_time, email.field_name, email.value
    FROM        dbplugins_submit email
    INNER JOIN  dbplugins_submit signup
    ON          email.submit_time = signup.submit_time
    WHERE       email.field_name = 'your-email'
    AND         signup.field_name = 'checkbox-signup'
    AND         signup.value = 'signup for our email newsletter'
```

I am not sure if there are any syntactical differences between SQL and MySQL with respect to this query. This works in SQL so the query must be similar if not the same for MySQL. Try this out and let me know if this works for you :)

Hope this is helpful!!!